# com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis

I am using [this](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-connectors) kinesis to S3 connector. While running S3Executor.java, I am getting following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:131)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:780)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:806)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:701)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:453)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:415)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:364)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.doInvoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1998)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1968)
at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.describeStream(AmazonKinesisClient.java:686)
at com.connectors.util.KinesisUtils.streamExists(KinesisUtils.java:150)
at com.connectors.util.KinesisUtils.createAndWaitForStreamToBecomeAvailable(KinesisUtils.java:82)
at com.connectors.util.KinesisUtils.createInputStream(KinesisUtils.java:41)
at com.connectors.util.StreamSource.<init>(StreamSource.java:66)
at com.connectors.util.KinesisConnectorExecutor.setupInputStream(KinesisConnectorExecutor.java:181)
at com.connectors.util.KinesisConnectorExecutor.<init>(KinesisConnectorExecutor.java:100)
at com.connectors.util.S3Executor.<init>(S3Executor.java:22)
at com.connectors.util.S3Executor.main(S3Executor.java:37)
```

I have setup Access Id and Secret Key in the Eclipse. It is working fine for another S3 sample project. But in this connector I am getting this issue.

Any help is appreciated